# How migrate products from Magento database 1.9 to 2.3.2?

Tags: magento2.3.2, magento1.9.3, data-migration

I migrate data from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.3.2, after that customer adds new products to 1.9, so I'm in trouble. I have a database with new products that were added at Magento 1.9, but I don't know how to migrate them safely and what tables I should migrate. As I know products records consist of "product entity" tables, but they connected to other tables. Here a screenshot of the database, and "**catalog_product_entity**" have a 17 products here. 1.9 site version is dead so I cant use admin tools for export, the only database available. 
[image]

Comment: You can download database, connect with fresh files and create a root script and export products you want

Comment: What tutorial you following migration process? @Ashen One

Comment: @zus My colleague migrated the DB, and left me this database with new products, so I don`t know.

Comment: @Pawan mb u have some guide links?

Comment: I migrate products manually - by creating SQL file with products entity records, but I have troubles with product id, so I just delete product id and let the MySQL generate it automatically. After that, I tried to migrate the product attributes, one of the tables is "catalog_product_entity_varchar". I replace old "entity_id" by the new one, generated by MySQL, but there trouble - attributes on table "eav_attribute" did not exist attributes from new attributes records.  a foreign key constraint fails.

Comment: Manually migrate all catalog_product_entity tables helped.